# java web development

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee

I am a novice in web development but I need to develop an application that will work in browser. But, the application should be like a destkop application. Application should implement simple functions like database table reflection, adding/deleting/updating table rows and calculating values based on formulas (I suppose here I should implement a java class that will make this calculations).

It seems to me I should use servlet+jsp but the application will not be static. Pages will always be refreshing. 
What java technologies I should use to implement my task? Maybe oracle ADF business componets in JDeveloper?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to dynamically update your JSP page

[Java - How to use Ajax in JSP](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=580) *(shows a simple example using JSP + AJAX)*

*Also See*
[Ajax Programming with JSP and Servlets](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/ajax/ajax-programming-with-jsp-and-servlets) *(shows a simple example using JSP + AJAX + Servlet)*